# Finding Probability of Intersection

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Given the following pieces of information, how can I determine the *probability of a randomly selected person being a **female and over 45 years old***?

$$ P(age < 26) = 0.25\\ P(age > 45) = 0.25\\ P(Male) = 0.55\\ P(Male \cap age < 26) = 0.12\\ P(Female \cap 26 < age < 45) = 0.23 $$

I've tried using a combination of the total probability and complement rules (see below), but nothing quite works out.

$$ P(Male) = 0.55 \implies P(Female) = 1 - 0.55 = 0.45 \\ 
P(Female) = 0.45 = P(Female \cap 26 < age < 45) + P(Female \cap 26 > age > 45)\\
\implies P(Female \cap 26 > age > 45) = 0.45 - 0.23 = 0.22
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you start by making a $2 \times 3$ table
and filling in the information you have. Then you can
use arithmetic to fill in the missing cells in the
table. With the completed table, you can answer any
question related to the gender and relevant age categories.

```
                       Age
          ---------------------------------
Gender    Under 25   Betw 26 & 45   Over 45    Total
----------------------------------------------------
Male        .12                                  .55
Female                   .23
----------------------------------------------------
Total       .25                       .25       1.00
```

My first step would be to fill in P(Female) = .45 in the 'Total'
column at the right.  Next P(Female and < 25).$  Then finish the
'Female' row. And so on.

*Note:* Venn diagrams can be helpful for some similar
problems, but a Venn diagram might be awkward here
because there are so many categories involved.